# how I move a cell from data grid view to another cell Which the user will choose in another data grid view

Tags: c#, datagridview, windows

I'm doing an organizing queues program <<, I need the user to move name in one cell in Data grid view to another chosen one

Comment: Please make sure you have read [these topics](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) first. There, you can find an explanation of how to ask a good question with a great chance to receive an answer.

Comment: thanks .. but focus in the answer This is the most important

Answer (score 0):

You can create a sub and insert your code here.

if you use `button` `Gridevents` like cellclick etc. then it will suit to your question.

`1st grid where user will select cells, If it is highlighted it means it is selected then you can use . . .`

```
Sub TransferData()
 Dim ctr as integer = dg2.rows.count - 1
 dg2.rows.add()
 dg2.rows(ctr).cells("Names").value = dg1.currentrow.cells("Names").value
End Sub
```